# Ansible what's wrong with my gem task

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to install a gem with Ansible, although Ansible is reporting it as changed. the `gem list` doesn't show the gem in question as installed. Am I missing something here:

```
 tasks:
  - name: Install Ultrahook
    gem:
      name: ultrahook
      state: present
```

Report:

```
changed: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "build_flags": null, 
            "env_shebang": false, 
            "executable": null, 
            "gem_source": "ultrahook", 
            "include_dependencies": true, 
            "include_doc": false, 
            "name": "ultrahook", 
            "pre_release": false, 
            "repository": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "user_install": true, 
            "version": null
        }
    }, 
    "name": "ultrahook", 
    "state": "present"
}
```

Adding the gem manualy is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`user_install: false`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/gem_module.html) if you don't want to install only for the current user.

By default it's true:

> Install gem in user's local gems cache or for all users